# Android and long running background task

Tags: android, xamarin, background-process

I have an Xamarin Android application. I need to start long running task in this app. As I know I should use class `Service` for it. I created a such class:

```
[Service]
public class BackgroundService : IntentService
{
    Handler mHandler;

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        SomeTask();
        return 0;
    }

    private void SomeTask()
    {
        // Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId here is 1
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            mHandler.Post(new Runnable(() =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, $"Current thread ID in service: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }));
        }
        StopSelf();                       
    }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
    }
}
```

And how I use the service in activity:

```
// And here Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is 1
var serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(BackgroundService));
StartService(serviceToStart);
```

I expected this service starts in another background thread but `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` in activity is just the same as the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` in method `SomeTask` of class BackgroundService. Moreover when `SomeTask`is running my application is not responding. Obviously it means the service doesn't work in background thread. 
How do I make the service to wirk in background thread/process?

Comment: `IntentService` is running it's `onHandleIntent` on the background thread, not `OnStartCommand`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I moved this code from `OnStartCommand` to `OnHandleIntent ` and it stopped to work because the application doesn't call `OnHandleIntent`

Answer (score 0):

You should pop up Toast in `OnHandleIntent` method and change code of `new Handler()` to `new Handler(Looper.MainLooper)`.

You could refer to the following demo.

[image]

IntentServiceDemo.cs

```
[Service]
public  class IntentServiceDemo : IntentService
{

    Handler mHandler;
    public IntentServiceDemo() : base("IntentServiceDemo")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
        SomeTask();
    }

    private void SomeTask()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int id=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            mHandler.Post(new Runnable(() =>
            {

                Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, $"Current thread ID in service:"+ id, ToastLength.Short).Show();

            }));
        }
        StopSelf();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    //string TAG = "DemoService:";
  //  private Messenger messenger; // Instance variable for the Messenger
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        int id = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        Toast.MakeText(this ,"Main thread"+ id, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        Button bt_service = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bt_service);

        bt_service.Click += (e, o) =>
        {
            Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(IntentServiceDemo));
            StartService(downloadIntent);

        };

    }
```

activity_main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/bt_service"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="startService"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If this answer is helpful, please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.